# How to make igniteui dataSource 2013.2 use local browser cache?

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui, igdatasource

I need to create a REST data source in two cases :

1. when there is nothing in the local browser cache - the standard way through ds.dataBind()
2. when there is something - by preloading the previously cached json result in it.

The browser cache may by any browser cache. I prefer [localForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage).

Is there any way through public API to push a json array into the REST ds after its creation and before databind() in order to prevent any inital GET/databind call?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built-in for the `igDataSource` to handle cached data over requests. My suggestion would be to utilize the `jQuery.ajaxSetup` to intercept the requests and use cached data if such exists in `localStorage` or anywhere else.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        // return from local storage instead of initiating the request
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - this really enables me to make the dataSource cache enabled. Do you plan to add an option for injecting caching provider to the dataSource in your future releases in order to make the dataSource 'cache enabled'?

Comment: There are no plans for that currently, but I encourage you to submit this through our product ideas: http://ideas.infragistics.com/forums/211535-ignite-ui

Answer (score 1):

I have come to the conclusion that it is not possible to do it this way (on the level of $.ajax) because returning from beforeSend does not cancel the request. On the other hand aborting the request (jqXHR.abort()) aborts the whole request pipeline which aborts the execution of all other $.ajax callbacks which is a dead end - the whole dataSource pipeline is then aborted which stops me from getting any result.

The only solution for the moment is to create different type of dataSource (JSON ds) during the creation of the grid (in my case these are the ds for the combos).

**Update**
It is not at all impossible, but the pipeline consisting methods _remoteData->_processRequest->_successCallBack->CompleteCallBack must be abstracted away in a state-machine like class. The problem comes from the fact that the state-machine is implemented via $.ajax which is not really conceived with that kind of scenario in mind and hacking it is not a good idea.

If there is a lightweight js state-machine library it can be done.